# kernel panic occured after installing wifi driver

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, modprobe

I have exactly [this problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2236922). I retype some of it in case link goes offline.
I have notebook lenovo E540. I think I'm using 14.04.1 LTS (didn't check) and kernel 3.13.0-35.
My wifi stoped working after few minutes and I could not get it going. So I googled for the solution. I found this:

From there I tried the solution in #29

```
I have tried the following on several kernels (under 12.04 and 14.04) and so far it has worked well :sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
# needed only if you don't have yet that package
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723be
# needed only if you don't have yet downloaded rtl8723be
cd rtl8723be
git checkout 604aa9058fb9e5bb1cf571c99989d081f8fc8b9
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8723be
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

But it broke my system. I get kernel panic because of rtl8723be driver. I try to load to recovery mode -> root shell and run:

```
modprobe -r rtl8723be
```

No output. Didn't help.
How do I remove that driver from system? I would like to avoid reinstalling whole system.

Comment: what about blacklist it in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist`?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works. I had to overcome read-only filesystem in recovery root shell, then added line `blacklist rtl8723be` into blacklist.conf file. Thanks again! (PS: why didn't you post it as answer? )

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question I just noticed its written in comment 30. :(

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, and worked perfectly on a Lenovo g40-30 so i guess it should work in other lenovo pc...

quote:

for one time test:

```
sudo rmmod ideapad_laptop
```

for working after reboot:

```
echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf
```

found it in: [Wifi Not Working On Ubuntu 14.04 Lenovo G 50-30](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507470/wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-lenovo-g-50-30/535976#535976)

but I don't know if you'll have to unistall the module you installed. Try it, or try to update your kernel, then the solution I found.