# Wireless adapter is not working in ubuntu 16.04 but works fine in windows 10

Tags: wireless, 16.04, rtl8723be

I recently bought a HP pavilion with pre-installed win10. I dual booted it with **ubuntu 15.10** only to find out that wireless adapter is not working in ubuntu. Some wifi networks are getting detected and some are not. But none of the detected ones are getting connected. I did `iwconfig` to find out that it is having **realtek rtl8723be** adapter.

I upgraded to **ubuntu 16.04**... Didn't work

I tried this.. [Wifi problems with rtl8723be in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04) ...but still not resolved

Then i tried this one as well [lenovo e540 RTL8723be wifi not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517772/lenovo-e540-rtl8723be-wifi-not-working) ... Still no improvement.

Typing modinfo -p rtl8723be in the terminal gave me this...

```
swlps: (bool)
swenc:using hardware crypto (default 0 [hardware])
 (bool)
ips:using no link power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
fwlps:using linked fw control power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
 (bool)
debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)
ant_sel:Set to 1 or 2 to force antenna number (default 0)
 (int)
```

I finally ended up using an external wifi adapter but couldn't solve the issue. Please let me know if there is anything else that is worth trying to fix this. TIA

Comment: Are the error symptoms always the same? Even with the external adapter? Did you make sure to deactivate the internal card when using an external adapter?

Comment: When I connect the external adapter, the computer automatically detects it and uses it leaving the internal adapter. No, internal adapter is still active and showing same problems when I try to connect with it.

Comment: Please edit the question to include terminal results for `modinfo -p rtl8723be` Thanks

Comment: Does `sudo modprobe -r && sleep 10 && sudo modprobe rtl8723be fwlps=N ant_sel=1` or  `sudo modprobe -r && sleep 10 && sudo modprobe rtl8723be fwlps=N ant_sel=2`  make any difference?

Comment: Its throwing me an error saying "modprobe: ERROR: missing parameters. See -h."