# Lenovo g5030 not having any hardware switch for wifi or bluetooth after installing ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking

In `rfkill` it shows wifi is hard block and bluetooth is also hardblock. Bluetooth soft unlock is working but wifi soft unlock is not working. Bios wifi is enabled.

Can any body help me fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the actual results of: rfkill list all Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try removing the ideapad_laptop module

for one time test:

```
sudo rmmod ideapad_laptop
```

for working after reboot:

```
echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf
```

I had the same issue, and solved for me.
(The solution can also be found here:[Wifi Not Working On Ubuntu 14.04 Lenovo G 50-30](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507470/wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-lenovo-g-50-30/510799#510799) )

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been fixed by me in Ubuntu kernel 3.19.0-26, that is now available for Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04.

If you are affected by this issue, update the kernel by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```