# Wireless Problems (Lenovo G50-30)

Tags: wireless, lenovo

I've tried all the fixes and ran out of Google.

At first I had to type "sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop" into the Terminal at startup for the wifi to work. Now it works after I did a more permanent Terminal fix I found here. But it stops working after around ten minutes.

Help! Isn't there a driver I can install or anything? This is the first time I've ever had problems with Ubuntu and I don't wanna install Win 8 again.

Comment: can you provide output of lsusb and lspci?

Comment: Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0652 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: and lspci http://pastebin.com/gBHhEtkX

Answer (score 1):

You can try what is described here:
[Lenovo g5030 not having any hardware switch for wifi or bluetooth after installing ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518473/lenovo-g5030-not-having-any-hardware-switch-for-wifi-or-bluetooth-after-installi)

basically try to write this in terminal:

```
sudo rmmod ideapad_laptop
```

if it works, the for make it permanent try:

```
echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf
```

for me it worked flawlessly...

Comment: It says it's not loaded. Hmm. Thank you anyways (~:

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to flag this question as a duplicate of the other (with the [flag] button below this one).