# Wireless hardware switch Lenovo G50-30

Tags: wireless, lenovo, wifi-hardware-switch

I wiped Windows 8 upon buying my new lenovo G50-30 laptop. The wireless is turned off by hardware switch. I have used

```
sudo rmmod ideapad_laptop
```

Which works, but I must re-enter the code everytime I turn on the computer.
I also tried thi code I found in the forums to fix the problem more permanently

```
echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf
```

but is not working for me...nothing happens.

Code used was found at [this link in the Ubuntu Help Forums](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518473/lenovo-g5030-not-having-any-hardware-switch-for-wifi-or-bluetooth-after-installi)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug. Ideapad-laptop module blocks wifi on this module. A kernel quirk is needed. It is possible just blacklist ideapad-laptop module, but some other hardware may malfunction. I submitted a patch upstream to fix it. While it is applied and gets to Ubuntu, you can use ppa with the patched module. It can be installed by running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/ideapad-laptop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ideapad-laptop-dkms
```

**Update** For those who uses kernel 3.19 this ppa can be removed since 3.19.0-26 kernel includes this patch.